# unable to understand which query I have to right first in join

Tags: sql, join

hi team i'm facing issue while writing join query
3rd question
https://learn.udacity.com/courses/ud198/lessons/279f3b98-a2ca-46ef-975b-e943daffc30b/concepts/e80fffa3-0f87-405e-8675-2d23a4dd51ce

I have written code for this

```
SELECT region.name,account.name, orders.total_amt_usd/(orders.total + 0.01) unit_price
from  orders
join accounts
on orders.account_id=accounts.id
join sales_reps
on accounts.sales_rep_id=sales_reps.id
join region
on sales_reps.region_id=region.id
```

but the solution is :

```
SELECT r.name region, a.name account, 
       o.total_amt_usd/(o.total + 0.01) unit_price
FROM region r
JOIN sales_reps s
ON s.region_id = r.id
JOIN accounts a
ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id
JOIN orders o
ON o.account_id = a.id;
```

i'm always getting confuesed which query I need to execute first. plese look into this manner .......most of the time i'm facing same issue while writing joins. Please explain

Comment: For INNER JOIN:s the order isn't important - technically. However, you should have an order that logically makes sense.

Comment: usually you can determin the order by looking for the joining Columns, but i doubt that the result differs from both of your queries

Comment: Remarkable if the order is not essential then can you please explain why my code is showing an error ???

Comment: Please don’t link to images/external code, add all relevant information directly to your question. What error is your code giving?